# Proof of an interesting matrix property

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a square matrix $M$ with $n$ rows and $n$ columns. Suppose $M$ enjoys a property $p$ defined as follows:  $M_{i,j} = 0$ if $i + j$ is odd and non zero otherwise.

Question: if square matrix $M$ satisfies property $p$ then prove that $M^{-1}$ satisfies $p$ as well.

Ps
Thank you to those who suggested how I can improve the clarity of this question

Comment: The "And so on" is not so clear to me. What are the conditions on $M_{4\cdot}$? Also write
$$M_{1,1+3k} \ne 0, M_{1, 2+3k} = M_{1, 3+3k} = 0,\ k\in\mathbb N_0$$
To make it easier to read. The text is pretty cluttered.

Comment: Thank you Daw I have made this suggestion of yours now.

Comment: A subclass of those matrices are diagonal matrices. If $D$ is diagonal, $D^{-1}$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries that are the inverses of those of $D$. So for those it works. Try using the formula:
$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\mathop{cof}(A)^T,$$
where $\mathop{cof}(A)$ has $(-1)^{i+j}\det A_{ij}$ as $ij$ entry, and $A_{ij}$ is $A$ after canceling row $i$ and column $j$. See if that helps.

Comment: Just wondering if seeing the matrix $M$ as the adjacency matrix of some weighted directed graph (say $G$) will help. Consider the walks with first step in the graph $G$ and the second step in $G'$, where $G'$ is the graph corresponding to inverse of the matrix $M$. Not sure, if we have the answer, but just some random guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your property does not imply that $M$ is invertible, so $M^{-1}$ might fail to exist at all.

However suppose $M^{-1}$ does exist. Your property (ignoring the non-zero requirement) says that every "odd" standard basis vector has its image in the span (call it $V_1$) of all odd standard basis vectors, and every "even" standard basis vector has its image in the span (call it $V_0$) of all even standard basis vectors. It follows that $M(V_1)\subseteq V_1$ and $M(V_0)\subseteq V_0$. Since we assumed $M$ invertible, one in fact has equalities here, for dimension reasons. Can you see that $M^{-1}$ has the same properties?

The condition you stated that entries that are *allowed* to be nonzero (namely those with $i+j$ even) are in fact *required* to be nonzero complicates matters. In the end you will want to know if an invertible matrix with all its entries nonzero has an inverse with all its entries nonzero. That is true up to size $2\times2$, but fails for larger sizes. Therefore, for sufficiently large matrices (can you see how large?), you will get failure on this point.

Comment: .. required to be NON-zero?